# AngularJS to Angular with Webpack

Tags: angular, webpack

I am trying to update my team code from AngularJS to Angular and I am following this [guide](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade#upgrading-with-ngupgrade).
In [this section](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade#installing-angular) they talk about `update` package and how to add a mapping for it. In the guide they use `SystemJS` while my team use `Webpack` and I am wondring what is the eqauivalent mapping I need to add to my `webpack.config.js`:

```
System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': '/node_modules/'
    },
    map: {
      'ng-loader': '../src/systemjs-angular-loader.js',
      app: '/app',
/* . . . */
      '@angular/upgrade/static': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade-
static.umd.js',
/* . . . */
    },
```

Comment: is it a good idea to use ngUpgrade for large angularjs enterprise application??

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be needing to migrate the System.config (and neither that systemjs-angular-loader, which I wrote only for systemjs).

Just npm install the upgrade package and move on.

Comment: a more practical webpack + ng1 examle is inneed while systemjs is not that common in production